# Delphi - Excel. How to Undo a Sort?

Tags: excel, delphi, sorting

In Delphi XE6, I am programmatically sorting data in Excel (2010/2013) via a plugin I am writing (in order to be able to identify rows for a later copy operation).  I do the (range) sort via...

```
  XLApp.Range['A1', LastSheetCell].Sort(XLApp.Range[FirstSortCell, LastSortCell], xlAscending, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    xlDescending, EmptyParam, xlAscending, xlYes,
    EmptyParam, False, xlTopToBottom, xlSyllabary);
```

Once I have copied my data, I would like to return the rows to their original order.  The only solution I can find is to add an extra column, add an integer (like a rownumber) and then when complete, sort on this rownumber column, then delete the column.

Is there any other way?  I have checked.. the Sort / Clear option is NOT enabled on the Ribbon menu, so this operation is NOT cancellable via menu functionality.

Comment: You have to remember the order

Comment: If I FORCE a save prior to my sort operation, is there any internal attribute, such as a rownumber, that is already available?

Comment: Why don't you copy the data and then sort the original

Comment: That probably will be the easiest... make a copy of the original sheet, sort on the copy, do my work, delete the copy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to assign the original data to a Range or Variant variable before sorting

set rngOriginalData=XLApp.Range[FirstSortCell, LastSortCell]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not a Delphi problem per se, rather a problem (bug?/feature? you decide, it appears intentional on MS's part) in the design of Excel automation; it happens in Excel VBA macros too.

Do a Web search on something like "Excel VBA Macro Undo" to get the dope and some possible (though klugey) work-arounds.

HTH